# Foreground Push Notification of Firebase in Angular 10 not working

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification

Am using **Angular 10** I need to implement **Firebase Push notification** I used the below version to implement that

```
      "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
      "firebase": "^8.2.9",
```

and script file for js as below

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-messaging.js');
```

But while using this **not able to get notifications in Foreground** but **getting notifications in Background**. I tried another version also **firebase 7.6.0** then some **AngularFireMessaging issues** were coming. Please help me to clear this issue.